# Retrieving a path when dealing with composer packages

Tags: plugins, paths

Within my composer package, I require a script be enqueued, I get its "base" path with `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` and then append `Assets/JS/my_script.js` to get the full path, problem is, if someone installs my package and uses it inside a theme, that function isn't going to work, yet the package itself is supposed to work just fine.

What is the alternative here? Isn't there a function that tells me the current path I'm in, no matter if a plugin or theme?

Comment: how did they install it inside a theme, Plugin will be included in respective folder right?